# Store Images(in binary format) From Database to FileSystem

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

guys!
I have a task to retrieve all images from Northwind database(they are given in binary format) which is located in the Categories table and store them as JPG format in the filesystem. I am really new to that and need some help. I come up with this but its not working at all.

```
private static void WriteBinaryData(string fileName, byte[] fileContents)
    {
        FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName);

        using (stream)
        {
            stream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = HOME-PC\\KRISKO; " +
        "Database=Northwind; Integrated Security=true");
        conn.Open();

        using (conn)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM Categories", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            using (reader)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    byte[] image = (byte[])reader["Picture"];
                    WriteBinaryData("C:\\Users\\Niki\\Desktop", image);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any error? then please include it...

Comment: *its not working at all.* that's a vague statement. narrow it down. why not working?

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issue here as below

1. your path to the file `C:\\Users\\Niki\\Desktop` could be an issue cause you may not have access to it if that's a other user account profile; not yours.
2. You are not providing an filename for the picture file as in this code `FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName);` here `fileName` variable has only the path and no filename associated with it

Comment: Do i need a file? I want to store them all in a folder as jpgs. The given path is just a sample.

Comment: @j.DOE You need to design a solution **before** you start coding. So what file name do you want to use for each individual file? You need to decide and add the appropriate logic to your code. And one more comment - make your variable names meaningful and accurate. If you are passing just a path to your write function, you shouldn't call it "filename". Good, effective coding does not just happen by chance.